# How to control non-existent data items in SSRS chart at runtime?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

we have created a SSRS report with a big chart that have multiple entries in values

its a line chart so it is having many lines ( as number of entries in the value section)

we need to control the lines that shows in the chart from our ASPX page

its ok to create a chart with one line graph in it
and its ok to create a chart with multiple line graphs in it

but the thing is the user should be able to select he want one line , 2 lines , 3 lines in the graph

so lets say the chart shows ( expenses, revenue , profit) as line graphs in one chart

if the user selects to see only revenue it should only show the line graph in the chart
but if the user selects expenses & revenue  so both line graphs should be shown in the same chart ( showing where they are intersecting if they are)

how to control this can i controle this by parameters and how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chart lines in SSRS report can be made visible or hidden with the help of `Expressions` on the range values. Following example show how this can be done in SSRS 2005. Steps **1** - **9** show how this is achieved in **`SSRS 2005`**. Step **10** shows how the same functionality has been made easier in **`SSRS 2008 R2`**.

**Step-by-step process:** **`SSRS 2005`**

1. The example assumes that you have already created an SSRS report and the report shown in screenshot #**1** will be used to demonstrate how to add parameters and hide the `Expenses`, `Revenue` or `Profit`.
2. Click on the menu `Report` --> `Report Parameters...` as shown in screenshot #**1**. Create three **Boolean** type parameters namely `ShowRevenue`, `ShowExpenses` and `ShowProfit' as shown in screenshots #**3** - #**5**. Configure the values and default value as shown in screenshots.
3. Once the variables have been created, right-click on the Chart and select Properties as shown in screenshot #**6**.
4. On the `Chart Properties`, select the `Data` tab. Click on **Revenue** under the `Values` section and click **Edit...** button as shown in screenshot #**7**.
5. On the `Edit Chart Value` dialog, click on **Expression** button against the `Value` as shown in screenshoit #**8**.
6. Configure the expression for `Revenue` value series as shown in screenshot #**9**. This condition will check the value of the parameter `ShowRevenue`. If set to **Yes/True**, the value will be displayed, otherwise the line will not be shown. Click `OK` twice to get back to the `Chart Properties` dialog.
7. Similarly, configure the expression for Expenses and Profit as shown in screenshots #**10** and #**11**.
8. Screenshot #**12** shows the sample report execution when all the parameters are set to **Yes**.
9. Screenshot #**13** shows the report execution when the parameter `Show Expenses` is set to **No**. You can notice that the blue line corresponding to `Expenses` is no longer visible.
10. The same can be achieved much easily in **`SSRS 2008 R2`** with the help of `Visibility` property available at the Values level. Screenshots #**14** - #**16** shows how this can be achieved in `SSRS 2008 R2`. The report also hides the legend label accordingly.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

**Screenshot #15:**

[image: 15]

**Screenshot #16:**

[image: 16]